# How to print a block of data in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, printf

I would like to print some rectangles one by one in a terminal like that:

```
  4 5             7 8
2               5 
3    : bool     6    : int
```

Which represents that, given an array `a`, the zone from `a([2,3], [4,5])` is `bool` and the zone from `a([5,6], [7,8])` is `int`.

So the key is to print a block of data in several rows, instead of 1 row as default. Does anyone know how to realize that in Ocaml?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Could you give examples of input and output for the function you want to write? And what is the type that you want for it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are two approaches possible:

1. accumulate your two-dimensional output and use a specialized print function which rearranges the strings in a way you wish
2. print to a medium with 2D capabilities like terminal or GUI element (to play with terminal screen, one can use a binding to [ncurses](http://www.nongnu.org/ocaml-tmk/doc/Curses.html))

The first approach is more universal and remains functional in spirit. For example:

```
let item1 =
["  4 5          "
;"2              "
;"3    : bool    "
]

let item2 =
["  7 8          "
;"5              "
;"6    : int     "
]

let transpose ll =
  let rec pick_one ll =
    match ll with
      | [] -> []
      | [] :: _ -> []
      | _ ->
      let tear (reaped, rest) l =
        match l with
          | [] -> assert false
          | hd :: tl -> (hd :: reaped, tl :: rest)
       in
      let (reaped, rest) = List.fold_left tear ([], []) ll in
      (reaped :: (pick_one rest))
   in
  pick_one ll

let multiline_print items =
  let by_lines = transpose items in
  let show_line line = List.iter print_string line; print_endline "" in
  List.iter show_line by_lines

let _ = multiline_print [item1; item2]
```

Depending on your needs, you may build `printf`-like functionality around this.
You need to route through a "layout engine" the strings produced by the functions in your new `Printf`-like module.